# how to make a method to keep its values in C# console

Tags: c#, ms-access, methods, console

I want to use the upload and download of data from a MS Access Database in a separate Method as from the main method. As you can see from the code below, the whole method will be recalled every time i want something from the method.

This is a problem because i first use `Database("2", "0", "0", "0");//Download info from Database` to download all the data from the Access Database to arrays in the separate method. Then i want to use certain array values at certain time for example `Console.WriteLine(Database("4", "1", "1", "0"))`
and at the end update the database with `Database("1", "0", "0", "0");//Upload info to Database`

The problem I have is that the variable will be recalled every time which will lead to empty arrays and variables. Is there a way to do all of the above mentioned in the same method so that the second calling (which is for data in the arrays) can use the data that the first calling (to download the information into arrays) had put into the arrays?

I know that you can recall all of the data from the access database every time you want something but that will take a lot of memory and therefore longer to execute coding.

```
static string Database(string sCalling, string sGB, string sType, string sNumber)
    {
        string sBack = "";
        string sPlayerName, sNameInput, sTemp, sFirst, sSecond;
        int iOne, iTwo, iOneD, iTwoD, iCounter, iUpdate, iLevel, iDamage, iPos, k, t, u, iLength, iPlayerLevel, iPlayerDamage, iNameSort, iPlaceHolder;

        iCounter = 0;

        string[] sPos = new string[10], sDamage = new string[10], sLevel = new string[10], sNames = new string[10];
        string[] sGPID = new string[6], sGPName = new string[6], sGA1 = new string[6], sGA2 = new string[6], sGA3 = new string[6], sGHPmin = new string[6], sGHPmax = new string[6], sGAmin = new string[6], sGAmax = new string[6];
        string[] sBPID = new string[20], sBPName = new string[20], sBA1 = new string[20], sBA2 = new string[20], sBA3 = new string[20], sBHPmin = new string[20], sBHPmax = new string[20], sBAmin = new string[20], sBAmax = new string[20];

        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=PokemonConsole.mdb";
        string queryString;

        if (sCalling == "1")//Upload info from Database
        {

            for (iUpdate = 0; iUpdate <= 9; iUpdate++)
            {
                sPlayerName = sNames[iUpdate];
                iLevel = Convert.ToInt32(sLevel[iUpdate]);
                iDamage = Convert.ToInt32(sDamage[iUpdate]);
                iPos = iUpdate + 1;
                queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= @pPN, [Level]= @plvl, DamageReceived= @pdmg WHERE Pos= @pPlek";

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPN", sPlayerName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plvl", iLevel);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdmg", iDamage);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPlek", iPos);

                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return sBack;
        }
        else if (sCalling == "2")//Download info from Database
        {
            queryString = "SELECT * FROM Scores";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        sPos[iCounter] = reader[0].ToString();
                        sNames[iCounter] = reader[1].ToString();
                        sLevel[iCounter] = reader[2].ToString();
                        sDamage[iCounter] = reader[3].ToString();
                        iCounter++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            queryString = "SELECT * FROM pokemonGood";
            iCounter = 0;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        sGPID[iCounter] = reader[0].ToString();
                        sGPName[iCounter] = reader[1].ToString();
                        sGA1[iCounter] = reader[2].ToString();
                        sGA2[iCounter] = reader[3].ToString();
                        sGA3[iCounter] = reader[4].ToString();
                        sGHPmin[iCounter] = reader[5].ToString();
                        sGHPmax[iCounter] = reader[6].ToString();
                        sGAmin[iCounter] = reader[7].ToString();
                        sGAmax[iCounter] = reader[8].ToString();
                        iCounter++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            queryString = "SELECT * FROM pokemonBad";
            iCounter = 0;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        sBPID[iCounter] = reader[0].ToString();
                        sBPName[iCounter] = reader[1].ToString();
                        sBA1[iCounter] = reader[2].ToString();
                        sBA2[iCounter] = reader[3].ToString();
                        sBA3[iCounter] = reader[4].ToString();
                        sBHPmin[iCounter] = reader[5].ToString();
                        sBHPmax[iCounter] = reader[6].ToString();
                        sBAmin[iCounter] = reader[7].ToString();
                        sBAmax[iCounter] = reader[8].ToString();
                        iCounter++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            for (k = 0; k <= 9; k++)
            {
                iLength = sNames[k].Length;
                if (iLength < 20)
                {
                    iLength = 20 - iLength;
                    while (iLength != 0)
                    {
                        sNames[k] = sNames[k] + " ";
                        iLength--;
                    }
                }
            }
            return sBack;

        }

        else if (sCalling == "3")//Check if on scoreboard
        {
            iPlayerLevel = Convert.ToInt32(sGB);
            iPlayerDamage = Convert.ToInt32(sType);
            sNameInput = sNumber;

            iLevel = Convert.ToInt32(sLevel[9]);
            iDamage = Convert.ToInt32(sDamage[9]);
            sPlayerName = sNames[9];
            iNameSort = String.Compare(sPlayerName, sNameInput);
            if ((iPlayerLevel > iLevel) || ((iPlayerLevel == iLevel) && (iPlayerDamage < iDamage)) || ((iPlayerLevel == iLevel) && (iPlayerDamage == iDamage) && (iNameSort > 0)))
            {
                sNames[9] = sNameInput;
                sLevel[9] = Convert.ToString(iPlayerLevel);
                sDamage[9] = Convert.ToString(iPlayerDamage);


                for (t = 0; t <= 8; t++)
                {
                    for (u = t + 1; u <= 9; u++)
                    {
                        iOne = Convert.ToInt32(sLevel[t]);
                        iTwo = Convert.ToInt32(sLevel[u]);
                        iOneD = Convert.ToInt32(sDamage[t]);
                        iTwoD = Convert.ToInt32(sDamage[u]);
                        if ((iOne < iTwo) || ((iOne == iTwo) && (iOneD > iTwoD)))
                        {
                            sTemp = sLevel[t];
                            sLevel[t] = sLevel[u];
                            sLevel[u] = sTemp;

                            sTemp = sNames[t];
                            sNames[t] = sNames[u];
                            sNames[u] = sTemp;

                            sTemp = sDamage[t];
                            sDamage[t] = sDamage[u];
                            sDamage[u] = sTemp;
                        }
                        if ((iOne == iTwo) && (iOneD == iTwoD))
                        {
                            sFirst = sNames[t];
                            sSecond = sNames[u];
                            iNameSort = String.Compare(sFirst, sSecond);
                            if (iNameSort > 0)
                            {
                                sTemp = sNames[t];
                                sNames[t] = sNames[u];
                                sNames[u] = sTemp;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                sBack = "Congratulations you have reach the High Score board!!!\nGo to the High Scores to see your position.\n\n\nPress Enter to go back to  main menu";
            }
            else
                sBack = "Sorry you did not reach the High Score board.\nBetter luck next time!\n\n\nPress Enter to go back to  main menu";



            return sBack;
        }
        else //Send required info back
        {
            iPlaceHolder = Convert.ToInt32(sNumber);
            if (sGB == "1")
            {
                if (sType == "1")
                    sBack = sGPID[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "2")
                    sBack = sGPName[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "3")
                    sBack = sGA1[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "4")
                    sBack = sGA2[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "5")
                    sBack = sGA3[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "6")
                    sBack = sGHPmin[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "7")
                    sBack = sGHPmax[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "8")
                    sBack = sGAmin[iPlaceHolder];
                else
                    sBack = sGAmax[iPlaceHolder];
            }
            else if (sGB == "2")
            {
                if (sType == "1")
                    sBack = sBPID[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "2")
                    sBack = sBPName[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "3")
                    sBack = sBA1[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "4")
                    sBack = sBA2[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "5")
                    sBack = sBA3[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "6")
                    sBack = sBHPmin[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "7")
                    sBack = sBHPmax[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "8")
                    sBack = sBAmin[iPlaceHolder];
                else
                    sBack = sBAmax[iPlaceHolder];
            }
            else
            {
                if (sType == "1")
                    sBack = sPos[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "2")
                    sBack = sNames[iPlaceHolder];
                else if (sType == "3")
                    sBack = sLevel[iPlaceHolder];
                else
                    sBack = sDamage[iPlaceHolder];
            }
            return sBack;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could achieve this by declaring your variables as fields of the class rather than as local variables of the method.

Comment: It does not help. The same thing happens.

Comment: @phoog I added it on top and then it gave me a object reference error. After some research i then added `public` in front of the arrays (which is in the class) and i added `Program p = new Program();` to the `Database` method. I also added `p.` in front of all the arrays being used. **after all this it still does the same as before**

Comment: @sgtBlueBird: If you add `Program p = new Program();` to the `Database` method, you will create a new instance of `Program` each time `Database` is called. And if you don't know what an instance is, then I suggest you read some more books on programming and spend some more time creating simple programs, so you will understand the very basics of object oriented programming.

Comment: @waka Yes I'm still a Newbie at programming. Thanks for the explanation. Maybe you know how to answer my question?

Comment: As @waka implied, the answer to your question is a bit beyond the scope of a single stackoverflow question/answer.  You need to learn about variable scope and lifetime, and the project you are working on is too complicated to serve as an efficient example for illustrating those concepts.  The fact that you tried to "add it on top" indicates that you may in fact understand these concepts, in which case it may be that you don't understand C# syntax well enough to use them.  If you post example code that gives the "object reference error" and the exact error message, perhaps we can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP basis: protected/public/private class members (**not method members**)